# Calling asynchronous c# function using ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call an asynchronous c# function from the client side using an ajax call.

I would like SampleFunction() to be executed asynchronously. But the issue is that the function is not being triggered at all. If I place a break point in the function, it is not getting hit and the control simply reaches the success portion of the ajax function.

jquery function :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Candidate/SampleFunction",
        data: { a: "test1", b: test2 },
        success: function (response) {
            // some code.
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error.responseText);
        }
    });
```

C# function :

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> SampleFunction(string a, string b)
        {
           // some code to be executed.
        }
```

if I re-write SampleFunction() as :

```
 public JsonResult SampleFunction(string a, string b)
        {
           // some code to be executed.
        }
```

The SampleFunction() function runs synchronously and the UI is blocked until the execution of SampleFunction() is complete.

Can you guys let me know if I'm missing something here?

Comment: in ajax add: contentType: "application/json",async: true,

Comment: I have tried that and it still isn't working.